# Find count of occurrences in an array of struct in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an array of 100K structs. I am listing below the contents of one such struct:

Iteration:1

BlockID:86

The BlockID can have values between 1 and 100. I want to find out the count of occurrences of BlockID. For eg.: BlockID "1" occurred 25 times; BlockID "98" occurred 58 times and so on.

I looked online and tried the options mentioned in these links, but could not get a solution:
[Matlab: Count number of structs that have a specific content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834172/matlab-count-number-of-structs-that-have-a-specific-content)
[how to count unique elements of a cell in matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285217/how-to-count-unique-elements-of-a-cell-in-matlab)
[Matlab: How to calculate how many unique strings are stored in the cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787023/matlab-how-to-calculate-how-many-unique-strings-are-stored-in-the-cell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `arrayfun` and `count_unique` (count_unique is not an official function - it's from the matlab central file exchange and can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23333-determine-and-count-unique-values-of-an-array/content/count_unique.m)):

```
ids= arrayfun(@(x)x.BlockID, struct1);
[vals, counts] = count_unique(ids);
```

**NB:** As pointed out by rody_o (though he/she missed the fact that the indexing is unnecessary) there is an alternative way to concatenate the, ids, namely

```
ids = [struct1.BlockID];
```

Alternatively you could create your own `count_unique` function if you wished,

```
function [counts, uns] = count_unique(ids)
uns= unique(ids);
counts = arrayfun(@(x)sum(ids == x), uns);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I was using arrayfun, but was not able to proceed further to the point of getting the unique values. I added just one extra step to what you have mentioned. Converted "ids" to a matrix using cell2mat and then the rest was the same. Thanks again.

Comment: @Sarvavyapi: Could you explain again why you needed cell2mat? The output of `arrayfun` is an array...

Comment: I am not sure why, but I got this error when I gave "unique(ids)": Error using cell/unique (line 45)
Input must be a cell array of strings. Thats why I tried cell2mat.

Comment: @Sarvavyapi: weird - there _is_ a unique that works on cell arrays, but also one for normal arrays... could you confirm that `ids` is an array?

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of simplicity，suppose there is a struct array of size 10 with BlockID which value between '1' and '3':

```
%generate the struct array
for n = 1:10 
    structs(n).BlockID = num2str(randi(3));
end
%structs.BlockID : 3     2     1     3     3     2     1     1     2     2
```

To find out the count of occurrences of BlockID:

```
count = accumarray(str2double({structs.BlockID})',1);
%count : 3     4     3
```

Now count(i) is the count of occurrences of BlockID of value 'i'.

Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use Matlab's own indexing techniques, in combination with `hist` and `unique`:

```
% sample data

a(1).BlockID   = 68
a(1).iteration = 1

a(2).BlockID   = 88
a(2).iteration = 12

a(3).BlockID   = 88
a(3).iteration = 14

a(4).BlockID   = 16
a(4).iteration = 18

% collect all BlockID values into array
b = [a.BlockID];

% count unique entries
[occurrences, entries] = hist(b, unique(b))
```

Output:

```
occurrences =
    1     1     2
entries =
    16    68    88
```

I always find it surprising that something as widely applicable as the `[struct(indices).member]` notation is known (or used) by so few developers...

Comment: Tip: You don't need to index when concatenating - the notation you mention is even simpler: `[a.member]` and is of course only universally applicable specific member types ;)

Comment: True, I forgot it is a habit of mine to write it consistently with structs you *do* need to index...

Comment: thanks everyone for your responses. I will try out the options and give the results here.